# How to show all dates in a horizontal scroll view

Tags: flutter

I want to have all the dates of a month in a horizontal scroll view. The current week 7 days should be displayed first and on scrolling right the previous dates should be shown. later on scrolling left the later weeks dates should be displayed an don tap of a date i should get the date in return. How to do this? I have tried using the below. It displays dates and scrolls horizontally as well but it displays only multiple of 7 and all the exact dates of a month. Also on tapping the date it does not return the position form listview builder as 0 and i returns the index.

```
Widget displaydates(int week) {
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 5,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print(position);
                },
                child: Text(
                  ((week * 7) + i).toString() + " ",
                  style: TextStyle(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
```

I am calling this like:

```
displaydates(0),
displaydates(1),
displaydates(2),
displaydates(3),
displaydates(4),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

You can get last day of month using below code :

`DateTime(year,month + 1).subtract(Duration(days: 1)).day;`

You should use `ModalBottomSheet` for the same and then pop that on selection with the `Navigator.of(context).pop(result);`

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(position);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      ((week * 7) + i).toString() + " ",
                      style: TextStyle(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          );
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Why should I use ModalBottomSheet? I don't want to show the dates in bottom sheet

Comment: then you can use function to get callback instand of your print()

Comment: Ok but I actually wanted the dates according to month here. Like in january 31, feb 28 etc. How can I do that?

Comment: You can get last day of month using below code :

`DateTime(year,month + 1).subtract(Duration(days: 1)).day;`

Answer (score 1):

I have created a widget that let me select date from a list and it is scrollable(along time ago). There lot of code but you can use the selected date under any widget which parent wrapped from `InheritedWidget`.

Here is the code(Note that I also created a package for this, if you dont like to write this much code for this):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {

  final DateTime date;
  final int selectedDay;
  final int monthDateCount;
  final bool isDateHolderActive;
  final Map<int, bool> dayAvailabilityMap;
  final ValueChanged<bool> toggleDateHolderActive;
  final ValueChanged<int> setSelectedDay;

  MyInheritedWidget({
    Key key,
    this.date,
    this.selectedDay,
    this.monthDateCount,
    this.isDateHolderActive,
    this.dayAvailabilityMap,
    this.toggleDateHolderActive,
    this.setSelectedDay,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyInheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget.selectedDay != selectedDay ||
        oldWidget.toggleDateHolderActive != toggleDateHolderActive;
  }
}

class DateIndicatorPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DateIndicator(),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class DateIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) => context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType();

  @override
  _DateIndicatorState createState() => _DateIndicatorState();
}

class _DateIndicatorState extends State<DateIndicator> {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  int selectedDay = 1;
  int monthDateCount = 1;
  bool isDateHolderActive = false;
  Map<int, bool> dayAvailabilityMap = {};

  void toggleDateHolderActive(bool flag) {
    setState(() {
      isDateHolderActive = flag;
    });
  }

  void setSelectedDay(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedDay = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    final DateTime dateForValues = new DateTime(date.year, date.month + 1, 0);
    monthDateCount = dateForValues.day;

    // Just to show how to activate when something exist for this day(from network response or something)
    dayAvailabilityMap[1] = true;
    dayAvailabilityMap[2] = true;
    dayAvailabilityMap[3] = true;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 68.0,
      padding:
      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0, right: 3.0, top: 2.0, bottom: 2.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(.7),
              offset: Offset(0.0, .5),
              blurRadius: 3.0,
              spreadRadius: 0.3),
        ],
      ),
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: monthDateCount, // to avoid showing zero
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return MyInheritedWidget(
                date: date,
                selectedDay: selectedDay,
                monthDateCount: monthDateCount,
                isDateHolderActive: isDateHolderActive,
                dayAvailabilityMap: dayAvailabilityMap,
                toggleDateHolderActive: toggleDateHolderActive,
                setSelectedDay: setSelectedDay,
                child: DateHolder(index));
          }),
    );
  }
}

class DateHolder extends StatelessWidget {
  DateHolder(this.index);

  final int index;

  final Widget activeBubble = Container(
    width: 15.0,
    height: 15.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final appState = DateIndicator.of(context);

    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        appState.toggleDateHolderActive(true);
        appState.setSelectedDay(index);
        print("Date ${index} selected!");
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "${DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime(appState.date.year, appState.date.month, index)).substring(0, 1)}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 12.0),
                  )),
              Container(
                width: 45.0,
                height: 45.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: (index == (appState.selectedDay) &&
                      appState.isDateHolderActive == true)
                      ? Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)
                      : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "${index + 1}", // to avoid showing zero
                      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          (appState.dayAvailabilityMap[index] ?? false)
              ? Positioned(right: 8.0, bottom: 5.0, child: activeBubble)
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i was looking at your code but can  explain why u used inherited widget ,i mean here we can also do our work in a single class too.............

Comment: @GautamGoyal Yes of course if you just need to use it in one class and do not need to reuse those data in other place you can do your own. You could pass a callback from the parent class also.

Comment: Thanks ,I have few more doubts like how can i use dayAvailabilityMap and how can i active the date whenever user opens the app so that he doesnot need to select todays date

Comment: Also, why in dateForValues you used date.month + 1 instead of date.month?

Comment: Your answer will help a lot, Thanks once again